# How do i change the secondary button text color with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Im fairly new to CSS styling, and currently loading bootstrap into my scss main file, where im setting some colors (primary, secondary, danger, etc.) as a theme.

However, it seems that my button text gets distorted as a result of the color-contrast function in the bootstrap/functions.scss.

I would like to keep using this function for all colors except the "secondary". Is it possible to override this and define the btn-secondary-color without going through the color-contrast function?

Currently my main.scss looks like this:

```
$primary: #44698E;
$secondary: #90A1BC;
$danger: #D3745F;
$hoverblue: #edf6ff;
$darkblue: #103E67;
$dragoverGreen: #bfe3bf;
$dragoverRed: #e8a09e;

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$btn-secondary-color: white;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+4+change+secondary+button+color+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Override bootstrap variables**

First you have to import bootstrap, then you can define custom styling for every bootstrap component.

for example:

```html
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.btn-secondary {
  color: white;
}
```

More info [here](https://bootstrap.themes.guide/how-to-customize-bootstrap.html)